# How to pass parameter to a function

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. In the below posted code, I created a function caleed "func", but as shown it does not accept any parameters. what i want to is, to make "func" accepts a parameter
that should be passed to "fs.readdir". in other words, it should be something like the following:

```
var func(path) = fs.readdir(path, (err, file)......);
```

so that, each time i call func with a different parameter, fs.readdir should be called with the new parameter

how can i do that.

**code**:

```
var func = fs.readdir(p, (err, files) => {
if (err) {
console.log('ERROR: ' + err.message);
} else {
    files.filter( (file)=> {
      console.log(file + '____' + fs.statSync(file).size);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: `function func(p) { fs.readdir(p, ...) }`…?

Comment: what is `fs.readdir`?

Comment: @Igor: A [NodeJS API function](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using ES6 :

```
const func = path => fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
        // ...
    });

func("somePath") // and call it like this
```

In ES5 that would be :

```
var func = function(path) {
    fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
        // ...
    });
}

func("somePath") // and call it like this
```

If you want to pass multiple arguments :

```
const func = (path, arg2, arg3) => fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
        console.log(arg2, arg3) // "Second argument", "Third argument"
    });

func("somePath", "Second argument", "Third argument") // and call it like this
```

Comment: Added an example with multiple arguments

Answer (score 0):

You should define `func` as a new function. You can use the arrow function syntax but using the `function` keyword is more explicit.

```
var func = function (path) { 
    fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + err.message);
    } else {
        files.filter( (file)=> {
            console.log(file + '____' + fs.statSync(file).size);
        });
    }
    });
}
```